# What limits can we set about life beneath the ice of Europa?

Tags: astrobiology, europa

Do we know enough about the conditions beneath the ice of Europa to say anything about the complexity of life that may live there?  Can we rule out macroscopic life?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_(moon)#Habitability_potential